# Appcelerator - How to disable system sounds when tapping on empty spaces on the screen?

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, system-sounds

I'm building an Android app using Appcelerator and I have a problem with the sounds effects when I tap the screen.

I only want disable the sounds effects when I tap in an empty space of the screen in Android. I tried it with the property "touchEnabled: false" and I was looking for in Google and through this website but I didn't find the solution at this problem.

Could anyone help me?

Thank's very much.

Comment: Can you provide us some of your code !

Comment: Any code would be possible, when you create an app these sounds are default when testing the app on the mobile phone. I'd like to remove these sounds when I tap the screen.

As I said in my first post, the only property I found was "touchEnabled" and this property doesn't work for what I want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is not something apps have influence on AFAIK.

The user will have to disable this in their Android device settings:
http://www.wikihow.com/Turn-off-Android-Touch-Sounds

Comment: But I don't see this issue on any other Android app. i don't mind sound, but there shouldn't be sound on things that are not a button. e.g. try opening the photos app click on an empty space